# Server only sending one message to client

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, client-server

My Server is only able to send one message to the client (HELLO), the client then sends a WORD message and after the server had received the WORD message it's supposed to send a word.

For some reason the server only sends the HELLO message and upon receiving the WORD message it never sends the next message (in this case it's GREEK). I've tried so many different things but it just doesn't seem to work.

Server code (only the relevant parts) ALL CODE IS IN C

```
 while (1) {
        if ((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, &destlen)) == -1) {
            perror("Accept call failed");
            exit(-1);
        }

        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) {
            //close(sockfd);
            talk_to_client(newsockfd);
            //close(newsockfd); 
        }
        else if (childpid > 0)  {
            //close(newsockfd);
        }
    }
}
```

talk_to_client()

```
void talk_to_client(int sockfd) {
    char message[1024] = "HELLO";
    char message2[1024] = "GREEK";
    char recieved[1024];
    ssize_t n;
    //cannot send more than one!!!!!!!!! WHY NOT
    write(sockfd, message, sizeof(message));
    while (1) {
        recv(sockfd, recieved, sizeof(recieved), 0);
        if (recieved == "WORD") {
            //send initial word
            printf("SENDING WORD");
            write(sockfd, message2, sizeof(message2));
        }
        if (recieved == "QUIT") {
            //close connection
            close(sockfd);
        }

    }
    return;
}
```

Client code (only relevant parts)

```
    char srv[512];

    char cli[512] = "WORD";
    // Connects socket to server
        rv = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) servaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        if (rv == -1){
            perror("Error connecting to the server");
            exit(-1);
        }       
        if(recv(sockfd, srv, sizeof(srv), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Client receiving error");
        }
        
        printf("Client received: %s\n", srv);

        if(send(sockfd, cli, sizeof(cli), 0) == -1){
            perror("Error sending message to the server");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("Client sending: %s\n", cli);

        if(recv(sockfd, srv, sizeof(srv), 0) == -1) {
            perror("Client receiving error");
        }
        printf("Client received: %s\n", srv);

        close(sockfd);
```

I tried many different ways to write to client (write, send, etc..) and I know for a fact it has nothing to do with my connect, bind, socket, listen or accept calls but this is the output I keep getting,

```
Client received: HELLO
Client sending: WORD
Client received:
```

Comment: The `accept` implies a stream protocol like TCP. You need to treat the input a stream, not as a message. If you need "messages" you will need to implement a (simple) protocol on top of TCP. It can be as simple as length-value.

Comment: *"Client code (only relevant parts)"* - relevant parts are missing. For example what exactly is `cli`? And what is thus `sizeof(cli)`? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  *"I've tried so many different things but it just doesn't seem to work."* - which provides exactly zero information of what you actually tried, i.e. this statement is useless.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I stated that the client then sends "WORD" back to the server, the client only sends one time so `cli` is "WORD", I added it into the post. I also said at the bottom  a couple of the things I tried, as well as a list of things I know have nothing to do with the problem, hence "relevant".

Comment: @gabekl22: *"I also said at the bottom a couple of the things I tried,"* - you mean *"I tried many different ways to write to client (write, send, etc.."*? This does not provide any information of what exactly you tried and thus does not provide any usable information.

Answer (score 0):

```
char cli[512] = "WORD";
...
    if(send(sockfd, cli, sizeof(cli), 0) == -1){
```

`sizeof(cli)` is 512 based on the definition of cli. So it will send 512 bytes. `strlen(cli)+1` would be more correct, i.e. send the string and the `\0` at the end of the string.

```
    recv(sockfd, recieved, sizeof(recieved), 0);
```

This will thus likely receive these 512 bytes in the server, i.e. `WORD\0` followed by many bytes junk. Note that I said "likely" since TCP is not a message based protocol but a byte stream and  a single `send` does not need to match a single `recv`.

```
    if (recieved == "WORD") {
```

This does not do a string comparison but compares pointer values. `strcmp` would be more correct here.